# How can I compile code written in services inside plugin in grails 3.3.9

Tags: grails, groovy

Whenever I make any changes in service inside plugin, I need to rerun the project for changes to be reflected. So, It is hectic to rerun the project for every small changes. Do anyone know any trick to compile the code without re running the project?

Comment: The behavior you described is not what normally happens.  Services dynamically reload while the app is running in development mode by default.  How are you launching the app?

Comment: when you are doing the changes inside the plugin, you should run this plugin in stand-alone mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix this issue by setting up a local maven for the plugin https://www.baeldung.com/maven-local-repository.

And in the plugin when I change any service or any other code then I run

```
gradle clean build
gradle publishToMavenLocal
```

Then in the consumer application refresh the dependencies

Comment: not sure but it works for grails with gradle dependency project

Comment: Could you please mention where can we keep the above config?

Comment: these are not config. these are command those have to run from command prompt. go to the project folder of the source . run the above commands. once done go to the destination project and run the command gradle clean build